# plotcandle and plotbar don't support " offset " argument like plot and plotchar

Tags: pine-script

I want to predict and generate candles and show them in the chart after current time but plotcandle and plotbar don't support the offset argument for shifting my candles that I determine their OHLC, but we have this option in plot and plotchar(Built-in function); how can I solve my problem?